# Difference between += and ++ in Java

Tags: java, math, operators, increment

I have a global variable that I modify in three different methods. It starts at 0, one method adds by 3, the next one by 2 and the last one by 1. They are all related to a button of their own.

When I click the "plus 1" button, the counter remains at 0 and I need another push to get it to 1. Interestingly, if I start with the other two buttons the counter acts accordingly but if I click my "plus 1" button again, it needs two pushes and acts weird like if it was holding the add...

```
 public void addThreeForTeamB(View view) {
    displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB += 3);
}

public void addTwoForTeamB(View view) {
    displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB += 2);
}

public void addOneForTeamB(View view) {
    displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB ++);
}
```

So that's the way it is managed, the cool thing is that when I change the last method to a "scoreTeamB += 1" it acts as it should, just adding without conflict.

My question is about the difference between this two operators to better understand the reason behind the slight discrepancy generated when using this 2 operators on the same variable.

Comment: you are using a post increment, you are rather out for a preincrement `++scoreTeamB`

Comment: Eran's answer explains the difference, but I'd *strongly* advise you to simplify the code by amending the variable in a separate statement *before* you call the method. Side-effects like this make the code significantly harder to understand at a glance.

Comment: **Don't put everything into one line**. That causes unexpected behavior like this, and has 0 benefits (although it seems to be insanely popular to shorten code). Here, this even worse: **do not mix *change* and *display* code**. That is an antipattern. Next, someone wants to remove the `displayForTeamB` method, and blindly deletes all invocations of this function. Thus, put this in separate lines at minimum.

Comment: @KevinEsche Thank you

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the advise, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks for the advise, it sounds very logical and I'll be sure to change my coding and yeah, shortening code is very popular. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`scoreTeamB++` returns the previous value of the variable (before it was incremented). `+=` returns the value that was assigned to the variable.

If you replace `scoreTeamB++` with `++scoreTeamB` or with `scoreTeamB +=1` you'll get the new (incremented) value of the variable.

Comment: I get it now, I mean it looks kind of obvious because the code tells me exactly what is happening, but because I have always used ++ for increments I've never gave it a second thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make this code work as you expect, you should use prefix ++ operator instead of postfix one. Prefix ++ operator(as well as -- operator, apparently) returns incremented value, while postfix operator ++ returns value of variable before increment.

Those may be implemented like this:

```
public static Integer prefixIncrement(Integer value) {
    value = value + 1;
    return value;
}

public static Integer postfixIncrement(Integer value) {
    Integer returnValue = new Integer(value);
    value = value + 1;
    return returnValue;
}
```